# Error when compiling autoware: members matching function of a non-direct base class

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, qt5

I'm compiling autoware.fundation tools, but when I build it with the instructions on the https://autowarefoundation.github.io/autoware-documentation/main/installation/autoware/source-installation/

I got stucked in the following error related to qt5 lib files:

```
    In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QTableWidget:1,
                 from /home/zhangchg/autoware/src/universe/autoware.universe/common/tier4_traffic_light_rviz_plugin/src/traffic_light_publish_panel.hpp:24,
                 from /home/zhangchg/autoware/build/tier4_traffic_light_rviz_plugin/tier4_traffic_light_rviz_plugin_autogen/UVLADIE3JM/moc_traffic_light_publish_panel.cpp:9,
                 from /home/zhangchg/autoware/build/tier4_traffic_light_rviz_plugin/tier4_traffic_light_rviz_plugin_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp:2:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qtablewidget.h:265:23: error: no members matching ‘QTableView::isPersistentEditorOpen’ in ‘class QTableView’
  265 |     using QTableView::isPersistentEditorOpen;
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QTableWidget:1,
                 from /home/zhangchg/autoware/src/universe/autoware.universe/common/tier4_traffic_light_rviz_plugin/src/traffic_light_publish_panel.hpp:24,
                 from /home/zhangchg/autoware/src/universe/autoware.universe/common/tier4_traffic_light_rviz_plugin/src/traffic_light_publish_panel.cpp:17:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qtablewidget.h:265:23: error: no members matching ‘QTableView::isPersistentEditorOpen’ in ‘class QTableView’
  265 |     using QTableView::isPersistentEditorOpen;
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tier4_traffic_light_rviz_plugin.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/tier4_traffic_light_rviz_plugin.dir/tier4_traffic_light_rviz_plugin_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

A snippet of source head code is

```
    void editItem(QTableWidgetItem *item);
    void openPersistentEditor(QTableWidgetItem *item);
    void closePersistentEditor(QTableWidgetItem *item);
    using QAbstractItemView::isPersistentEditorOpen;
    bool isPersistentEditorOpen(QTableWidgetItem *item) const;
```

(from https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qtablewidget.h?h=5.12.8)

Could someone tell me whether this problem is caused by my qt version, issue from the source code of the cmake files or balabala?
How can I fix it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I used conda to install some things I thought were necessary: QT and OpenSSL.

The QT that conda installed was 5.9, in which `QAbstractItemView::isPersistentEditorOpen` is not yet available. It was added in version 5.10.